# SVG + PHP + Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, svg

I'm trying to create a PHP generated SVG but I'm allready stuck on displaying a SVG file with an Javascript in it. The javascript is a pan and zoom function.

The code is:

```
<? 
header("Content-Type: image/svg+xml");
?>

    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <script xlink:href="SVGPan.js"/>
    <g id="viewport" transform="translate(200,200)">
    <polygon points="50,125 100,100 150,125 100,150" fill="green" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
    </g>
    </svg>
```

When opening this in Internet explorer, I can pan, but I am unable to zoom.

When opening this in Google Chrome, I the script runs correctly, it displays, I can zoom and pan but I get an error message

> error on line 10 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

I searched google for it, and stackoverflow but I cannot find a solution.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with a dangling newline. Is that the same as \n?

Comment: @Jack Newlines after the end of a document are fine in XML, so that can't be it.

Comment: @user1712197 Your code works fine for me at http://phihag.de/2012/so/so-svg/ with Chromium 21 on Linux. What version of Chrome are you using, and do you get the same error at the [demo page](http://phihag.de/2012/so/so-svg/)?

Comment: No, it works fine on the demo page. I am using Chrome 22.0.1229.79m. I work on Windows 7.

Comment: Possibly don't self-close the script tag: `<script xlink:href="SVGPan.js"></script>`. I don't have a windows machine at home, but I've periodically run into trouble with some self-closing elements in IE at work. Also, what is the actual javascript? IE can be quite particular about that.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but got the same problem. The Script is located here: http://code.google.com/p/svgpan/source/browse/branches/1.2.2/SVGPan.js

Comment: Also, when I remove the header, the page loads normally but then the Javascript doesn't run. But then I got no errors.

Comment: I think I have found the cause of it. I'm running on a free webhosting and see that the free webhosting adds a code at the end of the script: <!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
. Does anyone know a work around for this?

Comment: Try using better hosting such as Heroku or Phpfog. Also you might want to adress the fact that your script is using PHP short tags (<? ?>). This can cause issues with XML based formats (such as svg) an will not work if the web server has short tags turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are getting analytics code added which is causing extra output at the end of the file. Usually even free hosts will not put this on a file when it is getting served with the correct MIME type. You may need to ask their support how to get the image/svg+xml mime type served like the text/javascript mime type (i.e. without adding the analytics code). I have never used them, but cPanel and other popular management systems allow you to manage MIME types for many other reasons including this one.